# Multiple output cells

Tags: functions

Is it possible to have multiple outputs from a single function?

For example:

```
In[1]:= x+1
        x+2
Out[1]= 1+x
Out[2]= 2+x
```

has multiple outputs, how can I acheive that in a function?

I tried

```
In[3]:= f[x_]:=Module[{},
x+1
x+2
]
In[4]:= f[2]
Out[4]= 6
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use `NotebookWrite`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found this solution:

```
In[1]:= f[x_] := CellPrint[{
                    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[x + 1]], "Output"],
                    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[x + 2]], "Output"]}]

In[2]:= f[2]
```

> 3
>   4

I was originally trying to achieve something like this:

```
f[data_] :=
  CellPrint[{
    Cell["Data", "Subsection"],
    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ListLinePlot[data]]], "Output"],
    Cell["Fourier transform", "Subsection"],
    Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[data]]^2]]], "Output"]
    }]
```

which will generate two subsections

```
f[RandomReal[1, 200]]
```

[image]

Comment: There is no reason to use `Module` in the definition of `f`; `f[x_] := CellPrint[{Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[x + 1]], "Output"], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[x + 2]], "Output"]}]` works just as well

Comment: @m_goldberg yes you are right, let me correct that. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 3):

May be you are looking for :

`f[x_] := CellPrint /@ (ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] & /@ {x + 1 , 
      x + 2});` ?

`ExpressionCell[...]` replaces the complicated structure `Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[...]]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := Module[{},
  Column[{x + 1, x + 2}]
  ]
```

Then

```
f[1]
```

(* 2
      3  *)

Comment: But it is one output cell, OP wants each result in different cell.

Comment: @Kuba I would say that from his question I did not unequivocally see that. I have at least two interpretations of the question.