# Manipulate with formatted output

Tags: manipulate

I would like to have 4 output fields for something like the following:

```
Manipulate[
n*x
n/x
n + x
n - x,
{n, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}, ControlType -> InputField]
```

but this just outputs all 4 calculations combined.

Comment: Try something like this: `Manipulate[
 Row[{n*x, "," , n/x, ",", n + x ",", n - x}], {n, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10},
  ControlType -> InputField]`

Comment: Brilliant - thank you :)

Comment: Although this question arises from a simple mistake, I recommend that it not be closed because this is common problem for beginners, and the question and its answer is likely to help future visitors with a similar problem.

Comment: @m_goldberg but then the title should be improved. Perhaps: "manipulate with multiple outputs"? Of course the main problem here is not `Manipulate`, but `CompoundExpression` (and the fact that it is not needed in top level notebook cells)

Comment: Related: [Multiple output cells](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37584/multiple-output-cells).  One of the answers contains an answer to this question.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Right, the `Column` one. The other answers, using `CellPrint` should probably not be used in combination with `Manipulate` as this may lead to rather undesireable results. For that reason I suggest not to mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Artes, you can use `Row`, although you don't need to put in the "," individually. Row takes a spacing element as its second argument.

```
Manipulate[Row[{n*x, n/x, n + x, n - x}, ", "],
  {n, 1, 10},
  {x, 1, 10},
  ControlType -> InputField]
```

[image: manip.png]

You can get much fancier, of course. For example:

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   Row[{"n*x = ", n*x}],
   Row[{"n/x = ", n/x,}],
   Row[{"n + x = ", n + x}],
   Row[{"n - x = ", n - x}]}],
 {n, 1, 10},
 {x, 1, 10}, ControlType -> InputField]
```

[image: manip2.png]

For the ultimate in layout control, take a look at [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html).

Comment: Thank you - this is really helpful :)