# Multiple output cells, suppressed by semicolon

Tags: function-construction, output-formatting

I'd like to write a function that outputs multiple cells, as in [Multiple output cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37584/multiple-output-cells), but not when the function is called with a semicolon at the end.  Any idea how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New Implemantation:**

```
f[x_] := Dynamic[
  NotebookWrite[EvaluationCell[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[#]], "Echo"] & /@ Range[x]];,
  None, TrackedSymbols :> {}, Evaluator -> None]
```

---

**Original Answer:**

As `Dynamic` objects are only evaluated when they are visible, one can use them to print cells only when there is no `;` at the end of the input. The following one removes the `Out` cell containing a `DynamicWrapper` as the `Dynamic` object itself, after the cells are printed.

```
ClearAll@f

f[x_] := Module[{evalCellObject},
  DynamicWrapper["",
   evalCellObject = EvaluationCell[]; 
   NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook[], Cell[BoxData[ToBoxes[#]], "Echo"] & /@ Range[x]]; 
   NotebookDelete[evalCellObject]]]
```

[image: In&Out Example]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  Word to the wise: don't forget the final `NotebookDelete[evalCellObject]` statement!

Comment: One quirk (not a big deal for me): if you select a bunch of cells that make up a notebook section, then run them with shift-return, this doesn't produce output.

Comment: Actually I'm having bigger issues now, with input cells disappearing when opening closed sections that use this technique.  Probably not a practical solution after all.

Comment: @ChrisK The first two are very valid points. The issue stated in your third comment I could only reproduce by removing the `NotebookDelete` part (, which messes up a lot of different things). I implemented a new version of the same approach that is more straight forward and should also be more robust. Please give it a try and report back if there are any remaining issues.

Comment: I'll add some explanatory text for the new implementation if there are no issues left.

Answer (score 3):

The code below is currently broken but I'll leave it for reference.  I'll attempt a full rewrite somewhat later.  Thanks to [gwr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/764/gwr) for testing my code and pointing out problems.

---

The first possibility that comes to mind is the use of `$PreRead` and `$PrePrint` to set a global variable, then use the value of this variable within your function to control Cell generation.  A basic example building on [andre's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37625/121):

```
$print = True;

$PrePrint = ($print = True; #) &;

$PreRead = Replace[#, row : RowBox[{__, ";"}] :> ($print = False; row)] &;


f[x_] :=
  (If[$print, CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[#, "Output"] &] /@ {x + 1, x + 2};)
```

Now:

```
f[0]  (* "prints" two cells *)
```

> ```
> 1
>
> 2
> ```

```
f[0];  (* prints nothings *)
```

Comment: Seems like you need to drop the `;` after `$PrePrint = ...` for it to work. Also while it prints two cells they are not `Out[n]`and `Out[n+1]`?

Comment: @gwr The lack of `Out[]` tags is not part of this question; I am merely extending existing behavior as the OP requested.  However thank you for catching that bug; it's actually because I forgot to consider the order of the definitions.

Comment: Still nitpicking: `f[0]`will work, but then after `f[0];` another `f[0]`will not work. It only works *once*?

Comment: ... thus you need a "turn on" statement also: `$PreRead = Replace[ #, { row:RowBox[{__,";"}]:> ($print = False;row), row : RowBox[{__}] :> ($print = True; row)}]&;`.

Comment: @gwr Not nit-picking at all!  Thank you for debugging my disgracefully sloppy code.  I thought I could get a quick but valid answer in here and I overestimated my ability to write code without testing it.

Answer (score 3):

This one checks if the input ended with `;` and prints `Echo` cells if it didn't.

```
f[x_] := If[
  Cases[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]], 
    BoxData[RowBox[{___, last_}]] :> last] == {";"},
  Null,
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Echo"]] & /@ Range[x];
  ]
```

For example:

```
f[5]
```

[image: Out]

```
f[5];
```

This approach can be extended to also cover `CompoundExpression`s containing `f` by checking if the function is followed by `;`, instead of checking if the input ended with `;`.

```
f[x_] := If[Cases[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]],
    BoxData[RowBox[{___, RowBox[{"f", ___}], end_, ___}]] :> end] == {";"},
  Null,
  CellPrint[ExpressionCell[#, "Echo"]] & /@ Range[x];]
```

Comment: What about e.g. `f[5]; x`?

Comment: @jkuczm That input doesn't end with a `;` and therefore my first implementation is printing the cells. The OP isn't unambiguous about the expected behavior in this case. Thanks for pointing it out. I added an implementation of the same approach that doesn't print cells if the function is followed by a `;`, even as a part of a `CompoundExpression`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an intermediate expression that can be *returned* by your function, not printed as side effect. Then you can use `$Post` to post-process this returned expression, so that it'll result in multiple printed cells.

```
ClearAll[multipleCellsOutput, printMultipleCellsOutput]
printMultipleCellsOutput =
    # /. multipleCellsOutput[cells_List] :> Scan[CellPrint, cells] &;

$Post = printMultipleCellsOutput;
```

Example of function "evaluating to multiple cells":

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := multipleCellsOutput[ExpressionCell[x + #, "Output"] & /@ {1, 2}]
```

its usage:

```
f[x]
```

> ```
> 1 + x
> 2 + x
> ```

```
f[x]; (* Prints nothing *)

f[y]; z
```

> ```
> z
> ```

```
x; f[y]
```

> ```
> 1 + y
> 2 + y
> ```

```
x; f[y]; f[z]
```

> ```
> 1 + z
> 2 + z
> ```

```
f[x] + 1; (* Prints nothing *)

f[y] + 1
```

> ```
> 1 + y
> 2 + y
> 1 + Null
> ```